# Angular and RxJS - merge multiple HTTP requests, but emit the outer one instantly

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a hard time wrapping my head around some aspects of RxJS operators. I have some code here (in a component):

```
extendedOrders$ = this.salesService.getOrders().pipe(
  switchMap(orders => {
    return forkJoin(orders.map(order => {
      return this.salesService.getOrderCustomers(order.id).pipe(
        map(customer => ({ ...order, customerName: customer.name })),
      );
    }));
  }),
);
```

It is possibile extend it and do more then one call inside the forkJoin? For example, another call to another getById service and merge the response in the same object?

**UPDATE**

My first try:

```
this.salesService.getOrders().pipe(
  switchMap(orders => {
    return forkJoin(
      orders.map(order => {
        return {
          ...order,
          idAttr1: this.service1.method1(order.idAttr1).pipe(
            map(result => result.name)
          ),
          idAttr2: this.service2.method2(order.idAttr2).pipe(
            map(result => result.name)
          ),
        };
      })
    );
  })
)
.subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting confused by all the nested functions here. At least I am ;) I suggest to break all of this down a bit. Use a helper function:

```
this.salesService.getOrders().pipe(
  switchMap(orders => 
    forkJoin(
      orders.map(order => loadOrder(order))
    )
  )
)
.subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

Now `loadOrder` can do whatever it needs to retrieve a `Order` (which I assume is the type of `order`).

In your first example this would be:

```
function loadOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
  return this.salesService.getOrderCustomers(order.id).pipe(
    map(customer => ({ ...order, customerName: customer.name })),
  );
}
```

Now you can expand on this, the function gives you an outline of inputs and outputs, reduces nesting  and increases readability. Probably you want this:

```
function loadOrder(order: Order): Observable<Order> {
  // Observable to load idAttr1
  const idAttr1 = this.service1.method1(order.idAttr1).pipe(
    map(result => result.name)
  );
  // Observable to load idAttr2
  const idAttr2 = this.service2.method2(order.idAttr2).pipe(
    map(result => result.name)
  );

  // retrieve both via forkJoin and insert them into order
  return forkJoin({idAttr1, idAttr2}).pipe(
    map(({idAttr1, idAttr2}) => ({...order, idAttr1, idAttr2})
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this for the forkJoin method:

```
forkJoin({
stream1: this.service.method1(),
stream2:  this.service.method2()
})
.pipe(map(data => {
 const mergedObject = { ...data.stream1, ...data.stream2);
 return mergedObject;
})
```

But if one request has an error code the other one won't pass the value as well, even if it returns code 200

Comment: Hi, I need to insert a map function insidem the forkJoin, it's possibile?